# What is the difference between a vertical stabilizer and a rudder?

Tags: flight-controls, terminology, rudder, vertical-stabilizer

I saw two questions on locating these surfaces ahead of CG:

[Vertical Stabilizer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/51878/why-arent-there-aircraft-with-forward-mounted-vertical-stabilizers?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Rudder](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12055/why-isnt-it-possible-to-locate-the-rudder-in-front-of-an-airplanes-center-of-g?noredirect=1&lq=1)

How are these the same or different control surfaces?

Comment: I find this question confusing.  Are you asking about the conventional usage of these terms, or about how they would be applied to surfaces located *ahead* of the CG?  If the latter, that would see to merit mention in the actual title of the question.  Also, the two links no longer work.

Comment: @quietflyer The two answers provided cover all that I intended. I tried to update the links as the questions are on this site and are listed in the 'linked' section on this page, but they still don't work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [vertical stabilizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_stabilizer) is immobile (if it starts to move, [you're in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japan_Airlines_Flight_123) [deep shit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Airlines_Flight_587)), and provides stability in yaw (it keeps the aircraft pointed more or less in the direction that it's moving).

The [rudder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudder#Aircraft_rudders) is mobile, and typically attached to the aft edge of the vertical stabilizer. It provides controllability in yaw (it allows the aircraft, if necessary, to point in a different direction than the one it's moving).

The rudder allows the aircraft to slip sideways when you want it to; the vertical stabilizer keeps it from slipping sideways when you *don't* want it to.

[image]
(Original via [flickr.com](https://www.flickr.com/photos/28042007@N07/3418433749/))

Comment: Would it be possible to get a picture of a plane with a bigger rudder to make the moving part more noticeable?  Possibly something like an A-380 or 747 where the rudder is huge.

Comment: Where does **trim** fit in?  Does the whole vertical stabilizer move the way the horizontal stabilizers do on jetliners?

Comment: @Harper -- the vertical stabilizer is fixed -- rudder trim is usually provided through a tab or sorts on the rudder

Comment: @UnrecognizedFallingObject - With the controls being irreversible on the big jets, the rudder controller just shifts the neutral position (same for the pedals), regardless of airspeed.

Answer (score 4):

In order to deserve its name, a stabilizer **must** be located [aft of the center of gravity](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21653/in-aircraft-design-is-the-ratio-of-fuselage-surface-area-to-control-surface-are/21657#21657). Once it is shifted ahead, it will become a de-stabilizer.

The only way to laterally stabilize an aircraft with a vertical surface ahead of the center of gravity is to make it moveable and [actively controlled](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/12055/why-isnt-it-possible-to-locate-the-rudder-in-front-of-an-airplanes-center-of-g/12103#12103), either being slaved to a gyro or, even better, continually adjusted by a computer. In other words, any forward vertical stabilizer **is** a rudder.

Comment: "In other words, any forward vertical stabilizer is a rudder." Not true: SA-2/S75 missile's canards are definitely not rudders. They are fixed and used as destabilizers.

Comment: @user3528438: Exactly.  DEstabilizers.  Not stabilizers.

Comment: @Sean: Thanks! It feels so good to be understood.